# Converting string of XML with <?xml version="1.0"?> in it to XML

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, string, xml-documentation

I am having issues with  converting string to xml.string is in this format

```
 String s = "<?xml version="1.0"?><Brands><Brand><BrandID>1</BrandID><BrandName>ABC</BrandName></Brand><Brand><BrandID>2</BrandID><BrandName>DEF</BrandName></Brand></Brands>";
```

the above string comes as webservice response.

The main problem is when i have string like this with `<?xml version="1.0"?>` it gives error that "; expected" because of that xml header with "1.0". Rest of the code i have it figured out to convert to xml and all.it doesn't even compile so that i can go further.

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.LoadXml(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the " with \". So something like:

```
String s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><Brands>..."
```

Comment: ,I can't.it's coming like that from webservice response with double quotes.

Comment: It's coming as an invalid string? Can you pass the response straight into the LoadXml? Or can you show us how you're getting the response?

Comment: I guess you are right. Right now webservice is not ready and  I am hardcoding the string. once it is ready it will be not an issue it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a single quote (`'`) instead of a double quote (`"`) around 1.0

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, it's coming like that from webservice response with double quotes.